# how to use android json webserver

Tags: android, mysql, json, webserver

Hello every one I am new with servers things. I want to develop program that get data from the database on the server and it's my first time I don't have any idea of this thing.

Let say like Login & Logout:

1. how can i make a virtual server  for testing on my PC
2. how can i connect the emulator with this virtual server
3. how can i request the data from thee database

Do I need software like  Xamp or Wamp? If yes how can I use it?

I found so many examples about the json and webserver but I don't know how to make virtual server and connect the emulator to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand this problem you need two separate pieces of software. You will need 1) server. To begin with you can install XAMP and WAMP to get Apache running. There are millions of tutorials on how to set up an Apache web server online, and to begin with you could just return a string or a simple data structure (e.g. JSON or XML). As you want to do more complex things you can learn more, but in the beginning think "easy does it". From your text I anticipate that you just want to test as a proof of concept. 
- What OS do you run BTW?

Another solution is to rent some space on a server accessible from the Internet. Then you could test your server-side regardless of where you are located.

Second you would need to create a program for the android. There are several guides, but have a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html. If you choose to make your data available through the HTTP protocol there are very boilerplate-like procedures for how to download and parse the data.

If you are hosting the server-side on your local computer you would need to use local addressing, but if you choose to put it online you could acquire the data from everywhere as long as you have an internet connection.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much iam using windows 7 and i want to develop an application for website for the customers they can register from my application
but the problem is that i don't have any idea about the servers and how it works and after the investigations i discover that when i request something from the server database the server will send me json file or what ever ,all what i need is how to start from A-Z
   and thank you very much for your fast response

Comment: Very often servers return JSON. It's a very handy way of storing and transmitting data between services. Luckily for you there are also good libraries which helps you parse the JSON data into the data structure you may use in your web-page. Good luck!